# Is it possible to describe with 1 parameter when a wave is sinusoidal or square in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, fft, analytics

I am using scipy and I managed to filter the data with the fft package cutting the high frequencies, but that is only useful to transform the data, instead of that I want to get just 1 parameter after the analysis.

Let's have a look at some simple code to explain what I mean:

```
from scipy import fftpack
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import signal

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100, endpoint=True)

sq1 = signal.square(np.pi*t)
sin1 = np.sin(np.pi*t)

fft_sq1 = fftpack.dct(sq1,norm="ortho")

fft_sin1 = fftpack.dct(sin1, norm="ortho")
```

After applying the fast fourier transform (direct cosine) I get fft_sq1 and fft_sin1, which are arrays 100 elements long. Manipulating those coefficientes I can use later the fftpack.idct() and obtain a curve that does not contain noise.

The problem with this is that I get too much frequencies, I get 100 parameters I have to filter and after that I get again the curve.

Instead of that I am interested in a filter that returns me just 1 value:

0 if the curve is completely square

1 if the curve is exactly like a sinusoid

Does something comes to your mind?

Obviously there are infinite curves in between, if the periodic signal is more flat the number will be closer to 0 and if the curve is more round the number will be closer to 1.

Thanks!!

Comment: You should look at the FFT results of a square wave and a since wave.  A pure square wave has only the odd-numbered frequencies present in predictable proportions.  A pure since wave has exactly one frequency bin with power.

Comment: Ok I will look that more carefully. I will edit later with the findings. Basically I have to create a function that accepts as input those parameters, compare with sin and square and return the 0 or 1. It looks a good idea.

Comment: I assume you realize that most signals are not on the straight line between square wave and sine wave.  Most are just ugly.

Comment: Ouh yeah my friend, but this filter can be useful.

Comment: I hope you realize that the DCT is not the Fourier transform?

Comment: Yes but I don't want to get any imaginary thing here, so that method is ok.